# How can I set a solution of NSolve into the variable

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve an equation such as:

```
NSolve[Integrate[G[x], {x, -∞, ∞}] == 1 && B > 0, B]
```

when

```
G[x_] := (Abs[B*(E^-x^2) (x^3) ])^2
```

my question is how can i use G with the value of B which is given by the solution of the equation?

Answer (score 0):

```
G[x_] = (Abs[B*(E^-x^2) (x^3)])^2;
```

The definite integral is

```
int = Assuming[{B > 0}, Integrate[G[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]

(*  (15/64)*B^2*Sqrt[Pi/2]  *)
```

Solving for the exact positive value of `B` for which the integral is unity

```
soln = Solve[{int == 1, B > 0}, B][[1]]

(*  {B -> (8*(2/Pi)^(1/4))/Sqrt[15]}  *)
```

Verifying that this value of `B` makes the integral unity

```
int /. soln

(*  1  *)
```

The approximate numerical value of `B` is

```
soln // N

(*  {B -> 1.84508}  *)
```

Using the value of `B` in `G`

```
G2[x_] = Simplify[G[x] /. soln, Element[x, Reals]]

(*  ((64/15)*Sqrt[2/Pi]*x^6)/E^(2*x^2)  *)
```

Verifying that the integral is unity

```
Integrate[G2[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*  1  *)
```